# Why do I get this error when I try to install Android Studio on Windows 10?

Tags: android

This error is regarding Android Studio not being able to find the JDK, but JDK is already installed

I used `JAVA_HOME` and gave it a path name, but I'm still getting this error.

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the dialog message?

Comment: yes . it try my best :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the JAVA_HOME path is wrong. Try to check and fix it...

Comment: Can you past your java_home path? Try to set the jdk_home path also

Comment: you can verify JAVA_HOME is correct by going to a command prompt and typing `java -version`. you *should* get version information from the installed JDK

Comment: my JAVA_HOME path is "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05"

Comment: David M my java version is "1.8.0_05">>> but what is benefit to know about version

Comment: i also used the jdk_home path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05" please help me!!!!

Comment: so you ran `java -version` and got that result? i'm betting not. to do this  you'll need "java.exe" in your `PATH`, too